# Unable to locate cloudflare-warp on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: software-installation

I tried the reference, https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/linux
when I tried *sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cloudflare-warp* it says *The repository 'https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com lunar Release' does not have a Release file*.

Comment: You don't say what you have tried. Does this reference help? https://developers.cloudflare.com/warp-client/get-started/linux You should [edit] your question with further details.

Comment: @graham Please check the updated post.

Comment: Did you read *what* it supported; https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/ clearly shows only LTS releases are supported; 23.04 is **not** a LTS release.  *FYI:  The page was taken from your provided details*